# Closing a pyplot object in Tkinter while working with PdfPages causes the Tkinter instance to stop

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I apologize for the title but I couldn't think of a better description of the problem. I have a Tkinter based program that has an option for the user to generate a PDF report that consists of an overview, followed by some detail plots. I knew that for some reason the entire program would shut down after it finalized the PDF report but I only recently sat down to truly identify what caused it.

I found that the `plt.close` line in the initial overview plot, causes the entire program to close once the pdf report has been written (which is the first part that I don't understand as surely, if the `plot.close` is to blame why does the entire module run til completion)? Secondly, why does this even happen?

The minimum example that I was able to produce (with nonsense data for the plots) is listed below where if the line that is preceded by `# THE CULPRIT` is commented, the `Tk()` instance stays alive but if it's left as is, the `Tk()` instance is closed.

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from pathlib import Path

class Pdf(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        pdf = PdfPages(Path.cwd() / 'demo.pdf')

        self.pdf = pdf

    def plot_initial(self):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
        fig.add_subplot(111)

        mu, sigma = 0, 0.1
        s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
        count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 30, density=True)
        plt.plot(bins, 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) *
                 np.exp( - (bins - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) ),
                 linewidth=2, color='r')
        plt.title('Overview')
        plt.xlabel('X')
        plt.ylabel('Y')
        self.pdf.savefig(fig)
        # THE CULPRIT
        plt.close(fig)

    def plot_extra(self):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
        fig.add_subplot(111)

        mu, sigma = 0, 0.1
        s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
        count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s, 30, density=True)
        plt.plot(bins, 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) *
                 np.exp( - (bins - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) ),
                 linewidth=2, color='r')
        plt.title('Extra')
        plt.xlabel('X')
        plt.ylabel('Y')
        self.pdf.savefig(fig)
        plt.close(fig)

    def close(self):
        self.pdf.close()

class MVE(object):
    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        root = tk.Tk()
        MVE(root)
        root.mainloop()

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.root = master
        tk.Frame(master)

        menu = tk.Menu(master)
        master.config(menu=menu)

        test_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_cascade(label='Bug', menu=test_menu)
        test_menu.add_command(label='PDF', command=
                              self.generate_pdf)

    def generate_pdf(self):
        pdf = Pdf(self)

        pdf.plot_initial()
        for i in range(0,3):
            pdf.plot_extra()
        pdf.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MVE.run()
```

Versions of installed packages/python base:

- Python 3.7.0
- Tkinter 8.6
- Matplotlib 2.2.3
- Numpy 1.15.1

**Edit**

I have upgraded to Matplotlib 3.0.2 as per @ImportanceOfBeingErnest suggestion, however the problem still remains.

Comment: I've seen this happening elsewhere already. It seems that `plt.close()` does something which ends the `Tk()` session. This would only happen if using the Tk backend. So if using the "Qt5Agg" backend for pyplot, but keeping the tk app as it is would probably work - but is sure undesired in general.

Comment: I'll have a quick look at using a different backend, although that is not something that I really would like to do especially if the backend requires the installation of an additional package. Alternatively, I should look at the underlying `plt.close` code.

Comment: Note that if you do not want to actually want to show the figure on screen you can use the `"Agg"` backend, which does not require any additional QUI toolkit

Comment: Noted, sadly the program always uses the screen while the pdf reports are an optional output if the user desires.

Comment: Hmm, I searced through the matplotlib github issue list and didn't find any entry and made a new bug report, can you share a link to the issue as an answer? as it would answer the question (also the why part specifically)

Comment: Haha, I might have fixed that one myself in [12707](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12707). Which would explain why I have seen that issue already.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It hasn't, we should consider moving this to a chat perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises because: "*tension in Matplotlib between providing a low-level library to be used by application developers and being a front-line user interface. In this case, the niceties we need to provide for the end-user (ex, exiting the GUI main loop when the last figure is closed) is conflicting with how @Tarskin wants to use Matplot as a low-level library.*". For the full comment see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13470#issuecomment-465608779).

The problem is apparantly caused by `matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py`:

```
def destroy(self, *args): 
    if self.window is not None: 
        #self.toolbar.destroy() 
        if self.canvas._idle_callback: 
            self.canvas._tkcanvas.after_cancel(self.canvas._idle_callback) 
        self.window.destroy() 
    if Gcf.get_num_fig_managers() == 0: 
        if self.window is not None: 
            self.window.quit() 
    self.window = None
```

which quits the application when all of the figures are closed. This is essential for `plt.show(block=True)` to work (so when you close all of the plots we return control to the terminal). For the source of this go [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13470#issuecomment-465417954).

The suggestion was made to use `Agg` and while this indeed fixes it for now, the suggestion was made to ignore `pyplot` completely, when one is integrating matplotlib into a stand-alone package. Therefore, I have now fixed this by using just the `matplotlib.figure.Figure` class, as listed below (with a bit more nonsensical data, to avoid the use of `pyplot` completely).

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from pathlib import Path

class Pdf(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        pdf = PdfPages(Path.cwd() / 'demo.pdf')
        fig = Figure(figsize=(8,6))
        axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        axes.set_xlabel('X')
        axes.set_ylabel('Y')

        self.fig = fig
        self.axes = axes
        self.pdf = pdf

    def plot_initial(self):
        mu, sigma = 0, 0.1
        s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)

        self.axes.clear()
        self.axes.plot(s)
        self.axes.set_title('Overview')
        self.pdf.savefig(self.fig)

    def plot_extra(self):
        mu, sigma = 0, 0.1
        s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)

        self.axes.clear()
        self.axes.plot(s)
        self.axes.set_title('Extra')
        self.pdf.savefig(self.fig)

    def close(self):
        self.pdf.close()

class MVE(object):
    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        root = tk.Tk()
        MVE(root)
        root.mainloop()

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.root = master
        tk.Frame(master)

        menu = tk.Menu(master)
        master.config(menu=menu)

        test_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_cascade(label='Fixed', menu=test_menu)
        test_menu.add_command(label='PDF', command=
                              self.generate_pdf)

    def generate_pdf(self):
        pdf = Pdf(self)

        pdf.plot_initial()
        for i in range(0,3):
            pdf.plot_extra()
        pdf.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MVE.run()
```

The full discussion can be found at [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13470) github issue thread.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that the default backend used is `TkAgg`, change it to non-interactive backend, like `agg`, before importing `matplotlib.pyplot`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
```

Comment: While this does 'solve' the current proble, based on interaction with the developers I feel that it's better to avoid the use of `pyplot` entirely.